# nUnit Test function which uses executable path to open a file

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

I have a function which opens up the help file for the app. The function takes 3 arguments :

> ShowHelp(appPath, 1,
>   @"heelp\help.doc")

- The first argument is the start path.
- The second argument is the no of
  levels up the start path.
- The third argument is the path of the help file
  after going up n levels from the
  start path.

To test this I created a Resources folder in my test project, added a doc into this folder and supplied the below:

> controller.ShowHelp(Application.ExecutablePath,
>   1, @"Resources\h.doc");

However when I run this thru test driven.net , my executable path is coming back as :

> "C:\Program Files\TestDriven.NET
>   2.0\ProcessInvocation.exe"

- How do I supply the path of my Test Project in the test?
- Is there any easier way to test this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

you should obtain the path for the library containing the tests, probably something like (..\bin\Debug), and then you can adapt the other parameters.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Sometimes one must use the full path. Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location returns the correct path for NUnit tests. Application.StartupPath returns the NUnit path instead of the bin/debug or bin/release

Answer (score 1):

you should make your path relative.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/application-startuppath-and-nunit?highlight=application.startuppath&sentence=

in other words replace the application.executablepath with "/". See blog for more detail.